# How to ensure beamer's blocks respect margins?

Tags: beamer, block

I am looking for a way to have the outer frame of a [beamer](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) `block` environment respect the margins, and not overflow.

As you can see below, the inner text of the block is aligned with the margin, and not the outer area of the block.

`mew.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}
\usetheme{mytheme}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc
  \begin{block}{title}
  content...
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`beamerthememytheme.sty`:

```
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
I don't understand, what code are you referencing? The code in the image? That is the text in my presentation.

Comment: A small, but compilable test document which reproduces your situation. I shows you how to do this in beamer, if that's not enough to solve your problem, we need more information.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz You should have asked for a MWE, not to make my code compilable. Your response was confusing, as I included no code.

Comment: see my updated answer. You can use the `rounded` option to force rounded corners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `tcolorbox` inner theme. This will replace the normal beamer blocks with tcolorboxes of a similar look and feel and allows you to easily change the size:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}
\useinnertheme[rounded]{tcolorbox}
\tcbsetforeverylayer{
  oversize=-0.3cm
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc
  \begin{block}{title}
  content...
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have marked this as the correct answer, but if you have the time - could you elucidate why this works?  

From my (naive) understanding, this doesn't reference beamers blocks at all, and yet somehow modifies them? I am assuming that beamer uses tcolorbox under the hood, and you're directly modifying that instead?

Comment: Beamer normally does not use tcolorboxes. This theme redefines beamer blocks to use tcolorboxes instead of beamer's own boxes.

Comment: I guess I'm just confused on how I could have figured this out myself. tcolorbox doesn't seem to mention anything in its documentation about overriding beamer, and `\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}` isn't even mentioned in it's documentation.

Comment: Ah! I found it, its an entirely different package. 
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-tcolorbox